# Script to Shutdown Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I want to write a script which can Shutdown remote Ubuntu system. Actually i want my VM to shutdown safely when i shutdown my main machine on which my VM is installed .

Is there is any of doing this with the help of Sh scripts or script written in any language like Python.

Comment: I think you need to specify what you're using. VirtualBox? KVM?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i am using VirtualBox.

Comment: most virtual machine can session stop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the following command from a remote Linux machine (VM Host):

```
ssh root@<vm-client-ip> "shutdown -h now"
```

You will have to input your root password for the remote machine. You can prevent this by adding ssh certificates (good if you are writing a script):

[SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

If you make a script out of this, don't forget to add a delay after the shutdown (e.g. `sleep 10`) so that the VM will have time to die peacefully.

A complete bash script (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@<vm-client-ip> "shutdown -h now"
sleep 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hypervisor, i.e. the qm script in case of qemu/KVM

```
qm shutdown 300 && qm wait 300
```

It shuts down the VM with ID 300, and wait for the VM to stop. See the qm manual for more options.

Answer (score 2):

There are very many ways to turn off a Linux system.  The preferred way is to call your window manager's shutdown sequence.  If you're using `gdm` (which you probably are if you're using Ubuntu you want to use:

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```

If you're using `kdm` the command is:

```
kdmctl shutdown
```

Other ways of shutting down the computer (which may or may not be mostly or completely equivalent, but all require superuser rights) include:

```
/sbin/init 0
/sbin/halt
/sbin/shutdown -h now
/sbin/poweroff
```

etc, etc.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell i am using virtualBox.But my problem is i have to shutdown remote Virtual box through script...so in that case how will i enter the password from remote machine without ssh

Comment: you can setup sshd to be accessible without entering password, using [public key](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).

Answer (score 1):

The actual command with shuts a system down is shutdown, specifically

```
$ shutdown -h now
```

shuts it down now. This needs to be run with superuser privileges on the machine you want to stop.

Comment: How can i execute this command without logging into the remote machine...So please give useful advice ..

Comment: @VaIbHaV-JaIn: You do need to be logged in. You can set up login with a key so you don't need to input a password. Assumed that script has SUID permissions you could then execute it like `ssh HOST /path/to/script`.

Comment: @honk SUID on interpreted scripts is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `poweroff` from a script, as long as it's running with superuser privileges.

Comment: Yeah i tried what you are saying.But the problem is that when i poweroff Virtual Box it does not shutdown properly and it can corrupt the virtual Box...

Comment: @VaIbHaV-JaIn The `poweroff` command should be run within the VM; it will shutdown the OS within the VM properly. Once that's done, you can safely shutdown the host.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which virtualization product you are using (e.g. KVM, VirtualBox, VMWare, etc.), there should be a suitable interface you can use.

I suggest you search Google for the name of your chosen virtualisation software + "API". All of the above examples have relevant results that can be called from e.g. Python.

For VirtualBox, check out this link: https://blogs.oracle.com/nike/entry/python_api_to_the_virtualbox

That should give you a SOAP interface which should allow you remote control via e.g. cURL.

Alternatively for the remote aspect, you could setup private key authentication on the server and save your key's passphrase locally (with e.g. Seahorse), which would allow you secure ssh access without the need to enter your password each time.